# How to pass an index of a button to an EventHandler?

Tags: c#, arrays, button, event-handling, buttonclick

Good to know is that I just started programming, so go easy on me ;)

In my program I make a board consisting of several buttons (`btn[i, j]`), which I create by using two for loops. These buttons are given a coordinate pair/index `[i, j]`, then I pass this to a 2d array called `valueBtn` and I give that coordinate pair a value on the corresponding index.

```
        public void board(object obj, EventArgs ea)
        {
            int n = 6;
            Button[,] btn = new Button[n, n];
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    int p = 60 * i + 100;
                    int q = 60 * j + 100;
                    btn[i, j]          = new Button();
                    btn[i, j].Location = new Point(p, q);
                    btn[i, j].Size     = new Size(60, 60);

                    int[,] valueBtn = new int[n, n];
                    valueBtn[i, j]  = 0;

                    this.Controls.Add(btn[i, j]);
                }
            }
            btn[i, j].Click += btnPress;
        }
```

Next I have a new method `btnPress` which is linked to the EventHandler `btn[i, j].Click`. The intention is that in this method I find out which button has been pressed, and which coordinates/index belongs to this so that I can find the corresponding value in the 2d array `valueBtn` and eventually draw this value in a new function `drawValue`.

```
        public void btnPress(object sender, EventArgs ea)
        {
            Button pressedBtn = sender as Button;
            // Here I want to know which button is pressed and the index [i,j] of the button
            // so that I can find the value that belongs to the button in the 2d valueBtn array
            .
            .
            .
            this.Paint += drawValue;
        }
```

I've tried a lot with references to the EventHandler, but I just can't figure it out.

Thank you very much in advance for your time and help!

Comment: Look into the `Tag` property, you can store your data in it and then grab it out when you need it. Or create a new class, inherit the `TextBox` create a new property in that new class and set and get it anytime. Just a few options, there are other ways as well.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @zaggler! The Tag property sounds very useful to me, how could you apply it correctly in this case?

Comment: There are some issues with your code. Your `valueBtn` variable is declared in a local scope in a nested loop. So you can't get any value from that local arrays (n x n arrays, all of their elements are 0). Also, you are subscribing the `Paint` event with every click of any button. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Good comment @Steeeve! If I declare `valueBtn` at the top of the class is that enough to fix the problem? Furthermore, the board has to function as a kind of basis for a board game, so when the button is pressed (and the move is legal) then indeed every click of a button has to be drawn.

Comment: Moving valueBtn in a global scope is the first step. But if you want to draw something yourself in the Paint event handler, you only need to subscribe once the Paint event or override the OnPaint method. In btnPress you would only need to request a repaint, for example by calling Invalidate.

Comment: @Steeeve ok, I think I understand the first part. But what exactly do you mean by calling the paint event only once or how would you envision that? The way I see it now is that for example I can put the paint event in the constructor method of the class and then I put `this.Invalidate();` at the bottom of the class `btnPress`. Such that every time the click event is happening the paint event will "update".

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `Text` property of each button like `btn[i, j].Text = some i j combination`. and then get it in `btnPress` method like this  `string s = (sender as Button).Text;`. You can also use `Tag` property, so basically concept is same.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Yes, I was thinking about something like that myself, but I don't know if that's the most "neat" solution. And since I'm new and don't have much experience with `EventHandlers` references and using object things like `sender`, I thought I'd ask.